# Unity3D can't Destroy instantiate

Tags: unity-game-engine, scripting

```cs
public class SpawnerAI : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Aha Permintaan
    public GameObject[] Ahaprefab;
    GameObject Ahaprefabclone1,Ahaprefabclone2,Ahaprefabclone3,Ahaprefabclone4,Ahaprefabclone5;
    public Transform[] dupliposition;

    //artoolkit
    public GameObject ArtoolkitAc;
    GameObject au,ax,artoolkitAC;

    // Pergantian Permunculan AI
    public Camera[] cameras;
    public GameObject[] canvasall;

    public GameObject[] Aishown;
    public Transform[] aiposition;
    GameObject peopleclone1;
    GameObject peopleclone2;
    GameObject peopleclone3;
    GameObject peopleclone4;
    GameObject peopleclone5;

    private bool beingHandled = false;

    public bool pos1 = false;
    public bool pos2 = false;
    public bool pos3 = false;
    public bool pos4 = false;
    public bool pos5 = false;

    Animator Animdoor;

    public Vector3 Gcenter;
    public Vector3 TPosisi;
    RaycastHit hit;
    public bool touchedCh = false;

    void Start()
    {   
        cameras [0].enabled = true;
        cameras [1].enabled = false;
        canvasall [0].SetActive(true);
        canvasall [1].SetActive(false);
        Animdoor = GetComponent<Animator> ();
    }

    void Update () {
        if (/*some case  */ !beingHandled) 
        {
            StartCoroutine (HandleIt ());
        }
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) 
            {
                Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
                if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit)) 
                {
                    peopleclone1= hit.collider.gameObject;
                    Gcenter = peopleclone1.transform.position;
                    peopleclone2= hit.collider.gameObject;
                    Gcenter = peopleclone2.transform.position;
                    peopleclone3= hit.collider.gameObject;
                    Gcenter = peopleclone3.transform.position;
                    peopleclone4= hit.collider.gameObject;
                    Gcenter = peopleclone4.transform.position;
                    peopleclone5= hit.collider.gameObject;
                    Gcenter = peopleclone5.transform.position;
                    TPosisi = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition);                 
                    touchedCh = true;
                }
            }
            if (Input.GetMouseButton (0)) {
                if (touchedCh) {
                    TPosisi = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition); 
                    cameras [0].enabled = false;
                    cameras [1].enabled = true;
                    canvasall [0].SetActive(false);
                    canvasall [1].SetActive(true);
                    //artoolkitAC.SetActive (true);
                    if (pos1==true) {
                        //pos1 = false;
                        Destroy(peopleclone1);
                    Destroy(GameObject.FindWithTag("Aha1"));
                        Debug.Log ("Posisi kesatu Kosong");
                    }
                    else if (pos2==true) {
                        //pos2 = false;
                        Destroy(peopleclone2);
                    Destroy(GameObject.FindWithTag("Aha2"));
                        Debug.Log ("Posisi kedua Kosong");
                    }
                    else if (pos3==true) {
                        //pos3 = false;
                        Destroy(peopleclone3);
                    Destroy(GameObject.FindWithTag("Aha3"));

                        Debug.Log ("Posisi ketiga Kosong");
                    }
                    else if (pos4==true) {
                        //pos4 = false;
                        Destroy(peopleclone4);
                    Destroy(GameObject.FindWithTag("Aha4"));
                    }
                    else if (pos5==true) {
                        //pos5 = false;
                        Destroy(peopleclone5);
                    Destroy(GameObject.FindWithTag("Aha5"));
                        Debug.Log ("Posisi kelima Kosong");
                    }

                }
            }
            if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)){
                touchedCh= false;
            }
        //StartCoroutine(InfiniteLoop());
    }

    private IEnumerator HandleIt()
    {
        // AI
        beingHandled = true;
        int indAi = Random.Range (0, Aishown.Length);

        // process pre-yield
        Animdoor.SetInteger ("StateOP", 0);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds( 3.0f );
        if (pos1 == false) {
            // process post-yield
            yield return new WaitForSeconds( 8.0f );
            Animdoor.SetInteger ("StateOP", 1);
            GameObject.Find ("Bell").GetComponent<AudioSource> ().Play ();
            GameObject.Find ("doorclose").GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play ();
            peopleclone1 = Instantiate (Aishown [indAi], aiposition [0].position, Aishown [indAi].transform.rotation) as GameObject;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds( 2.0f );
            Ahaprefabclone1 = Instantiate (Ahaprefab[0], dupliposition [0].position, Quaternion.identity)as GameObject;
            beingHandled = false;
            pos1 = true;

            Debug.Log ("Posisi Pertama telah diisi");
            }
        else if (pos2 == false) {
            // process post-yield
            yield return new WaitForSeconds( 8.0f );
            Animdoor.SetInteger ("StateOP", 1);
            GameObject.Find ("Bell").GetComponent<AudioSource> ().Play ();
            GameObject.Find ("doorclose").GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play ();
            peopleclone2 = Instantiate (Aishown [indAi], aiposition [1].position, Aishown [indAi].transform.rotation) as GameObject;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds( 2.0f );
            Ahaprefabclone2 = Instantiate (Ahaprefab[1], dupliposition [1].position, Quaternion.identity)as GameObject;
            beingHandled = false;
            pos2 = true;
            Debug.Log ("Posisi Kedua telah diisi");
            }
        else if (pos3 == false) {
            // process post-yield
            yield return new WaitForSeconds( 8.0f );
            Animdoor.SetInteger ("StateOP", 1);
            GameObject.Find ("Bell").GetComponent<AudioSource> ().Play ();
            GameObject.Find ("doorclose").GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play ();
            peopleclone3 = Instantiate (Aishown [indAi], aiposition [2].position, Aishown [indAi].transform.rotation) as GameObject;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds( 2.0f );
            Ahaprefabclone3 = Instantiate (Ahaprefab[2], dupliposition [2].position,Quaternion.identity)as GameObject;
            beingHandled = false;
            pos3 = true;
            Debug.Log ("Posisi Ketiga telah diisi");
            }
        else if (pos4 == false) {
            // process post-yield
            yield return new WaitForSeconds( 8.0f );
            Animdoor.SetInteger ("StateOP", 1);
            GameObject.Find ("Bell").GetComponent<AudioSource> ().Play ();
            GameObject.Find ("doorclose").GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play ();
            peopleclone4 = Instantiate (Aishown [indAi], aiposition [3].position, Aishown [indAi].transform.rotation) as GameObject;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds( 2.0f );
            Ahaprefabclone4 = Instantiate (Ahaprefab[3], dupliposition [3].position, Quaternion.identity)as GameObject;
            beingHandled = false;
            pos4 = true;
            Debug.Log ("Posisi Keempat telah diisi");
            }
        else if (pos5 == false) {
            // process post-yield
            yield return new WaitForSeconds( 8.0f );
            Animdoor.SetInteger ("StateOP", 1);
            GameObject.Find ("Bell").GetComponent<AudioSource> ().Play ();
            GameObject.Find ("doorclose").GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play ();
            peopleclone5 = Instantiate (Aishown [indAi], aiposition [4].position, Aishown [indAi].transform.rotation) as GameObject;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds( 2.0f );
            Ahaprefabclone5 = Instantiate (Ahaprefab[4], dupliposition [4].position, Quaternion.identity)as GameObject;
            beingHandled = false;
            pos5 = true;
            Debug.Log ("Posisi Kelima telah diisi");
        }
        //artoolkitAC = Instantiate (ArtoolkitAc) as GameObject;
        //artoolkitAC.SetActive (false);
    }


    public void BacktoGameShop()
    {

        cameras [0].enabled = true;
        cameras [1].enabled = false;
        canvasall [0].SetActive(true);
        canvasall [1].SetActive(false);
    }

    // End Of code
}
```

I tried many methods to destroy an instance object, but it does not get destroyed.

1. first I tried it with:

> Destroy(ahaprefab1);

2. second I tried it with tag:

> Destroy(GameObject.FindWithTag("Aha1"));

It still does not destroy the instance. But when i use it for Spawner Ai.  Destroy(peopleclone1) does destroy the instance.

I'm stuck in this code.

Comment: Stupid comment, but will Destroy(peopleclone1.gameObject) work?

Comment: sorry, that's can't work.

Comment: Ok. Are you sure, that part of code where you call Destroy method is executed. I see you have a lot of IF conditions.

Comment: it can't work. that's make destroy my own prefab.  my problem is why in same parent it can't work it destroy.

Comment: My problem on this script mny method i try can't destroy. like gameobject have many parent when instantiate.

Destroy(GameObject.FindWithTag("Aha2"));

Comment: Add debugging statements to insure that the `Destroy()` method is, indeed, being called.  If not, figure out why not. If they are, then it should work. Your syntax is fine, `Destroy(peopleclone1)` is correct (as would `Destroy(Ahaprefabclone1)`).

Answer (score 0):

well , would advice to first check if you object are not just null `Debug.Log(peopleclone1)`

if it's not null , try to use `DestroyImmediate(peopleclone1)`since the reason the gameobject is not destroy may be because he still actioning some stuff

if even DestroyImmediate don't work , then I don't realy know what to do :/